# Display Result of Javascript & HTML in Blogger Post

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

This is the javascript & html code i have.

```
function convertinput() {
    document.getElementById('first').value
    var string = document.getElementById('first').value
    var newString = "@@[0:1: " + string + "]]"
    document.getElementById('output').value = newString
}
```

​

```
<input id="first"></input>
<br>
<input id="output"></input>
<br>
<input type='button' onclick='convertinput()' value='convert'>
​
```

the code editor in jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/FEC7S/3/

I want this code to be displayed in my blog post as it is here
http://www.trickiezone.com/2012/10/facebook-blue-text-generator-by.html

If i embed it in my blog through jsfiddle or tinkerbin, the whole web page is getting displayed.
I need only the result to be displayed in my blog post.

How to do so ?

Comment: do you even want button to be displayed?

Comment: can u post some link where u have done this

Comment: im not sure what you want to achieve plz explain it better

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Yes, i need the convert button to be displayed even.

Comment: @jade here the jsfiddle editor is.
http://jsfiddle.net/FEC7S/3/

Comment: @magicramki:and from where you are gonna take user input for conversion.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar The first box would be the visitor's input & the output will be displayed in the second box on clicking the 'convert' button.

Comment: so if a user clicks convert the result box should show up?

Comment: @magicramki:I have seen the link you have posted,you dont need fiddle for that.you can directly put this code inside your blog.with little bit of formatting it'll work the way you want.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar can you assist in what sort of changes i should make ?

Comment: set display of output to none and set it back to block in your convert function... like this http://jsfiddle.net/FEC7S/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have added the working demo in my blog:

[signed by miliodiguine](http://milindanantwar.blogspot.in/)

TO DO:

1)Login to your blog.

2)Add New Post

3)paste this code

```
<div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<br />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function convertinput() {
    document.getElementById('first').value
    var string = document.getElementById('first').value
    var newString = "@@[0:1: " + string + "]]"
    document.getElementById('output').value = newString
}
</script>

<input id="first"></input>
<br>
 <input id="output"></input>
<br>
<input type='button' onclick='convertinput()' value='convert'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what i really required.
Thanks for your effort & time spent for me here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your id to set the display property in css...

```
function convertinput() {
    document.getElementById('output').value = "@@[0:1: " + document.getElementById('first').value + "]]";
   document.getElementById('output').style.display = 'block';
}



<input id="first"></input>
<br>
<input id="output" style="display:none;"></input>
<br>
<input type='button' onclick='convertinput()' value='convert'>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FEC7S/7/

Comment: in jsfiddle it works like a charm. i need just the result pane(bottom right) in jsfiddle editor to be displayed in my blog post if i embed it.

Comment: so the input should disapere if one klicks on convert?

Comment: not at all. just see here.
http://www.trickiezone.com/2012/10/facebook-blue-text-generator-by.html
here the code had been used to display just the boxes & generate button.
I need a kind of same thing with just two boxes & a button to be displayed on my blog post.

Comment: sry i dont know what you want to do if you embed the above code it should work

Comment: so no need to hide the result before one clicks convert, sry im quite confused

Comment: actually, what i need is exactly answered above. Thanks for your time & effort :)